# Aerogel winter window quilt?

Tags: insulation, windows, energy-efficiency, materials, winter

1. Would it possibly make sense for me to use aerogel as a seasonal window quilt? It may depend critically on some other factors; if so, what are they?
2. In particular, I have heard that aerogel designed for insulation has the following properties which led me to consider it. Are these accurate?

- I have heard that it is translucent.
- I have heard that it squishes fairly well against irregular surfaces and does not lose much of its insulating value when compressed.
- I have heard that it is fairly resistant to coming apart if it catches on stuff.
- I have heard that it has an r-value of about 10 per inch or more, under "normal" conditions.
- I have heard that it is less likely (given current knowledge) to pose health risks than fiberglass.
- I've heard that it can be had for about $30 per cubic foot in 2020.

3. I'm pretty sure that "aerogel" is a pretty broad class of materials. If I am looking for "insulating aerogel," what descriptors should I look for to make sure I am not buying some other kind of aerogel?
4. It is possible that this question has too many "subcomponents" and will need to be split up; sorry if that's the case.

Comment: isn't aerogel similar to fiberglass in composition? ... the structure is different ... the health risks would probably be the same

Comment: thanks @jsotola; I don't understand the chemistry, but now that you mention it the following document suggests there could actually be similar health risks, I think: https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/hhe/reports/pdfs/2014-0026-3230.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aerogel is brittle, easily damaged and extremely expensive. Thirty dollars per cubic inch sounds more likely than per cubic foot. There's a [web site for aerogel](http://www.buyaerogel.com/product/classic-silica-disc/) and related products. The linked product is a silica disk, about an inch around and less than 3/8" thick. US$35 fits in with the expected price.

The same site also offers [composite blankets](http://www.buyaerogel.com/product/spaceloft/). It's a combination of aerogel and other insulating materials. Two feet by four feet by 5 mm for US$180 still falls into the expensive category, but that's my opinion.

There's no R factor in the main ad copy, but the spec sheet is available for download and may include that information.

Aerogel is silica and in powder form can be a problem if inhaled. Any product of that nature is a health concern. Don't shred it or otherwise damage it and the risk is low.

Comment: You're right about the cubic inch vs foot. I will mark this as the answer tomorrow. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: While I have you, what would you think about the following application: Stick a sheet of aerogel inside my window frame at the start of the winter, then apply a layer of shrink film like (this)[https://www.frostking.com/products/window-kits/indoor-shrink-window-kits] on the interior side, to try to protect the aerogel from me and me from dust. Also how translucent would that be?

Comment: I'm going to guess that you mean the insulating blanket and not the pure aerogel. The blanket appears to be completely opaque.

Comment: That's what I probably should have meant in the original question, but for the shrink film question I think I mean just the aerogel? I was hoping that the fragility of the aerogel would be okay if it was protected from me by the plastic.